# Every non-zero submodule of $R_R$ has an indecomposable direct summand: True when $R$ is von Neumann regular?

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings

Let's say that a (right) module $M$ is *well complemented* if every non-zero submodule of $M$ has an indecomposable direct summand (by the way, is there a better or more standard name for this property?). For instance, every module of finite [uniform dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_module#Uniform_dimension_of_a_module) is well complemented.

> **Question.** Is the regular right module $R_R$ of a von Neumann regular ring $R$ well complemented?

As a recall, a ring $R$ is *von Neumann regular* if, for every $x \in R$, there exists $y \in R$ such that $x = xyx$.

Comment: I think if you take an atomless boolean algebra the corresponding boolean ring is regular but has no primitive idempotents so no indecomposable summands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no.  Take a compact totally disconnected space $X$ with no isolated points, like the Cantor set.  Let $K$ be any field and let $R$ be the ring of locally constant functions $f\colon X\to K$ with pointwise operations.  This is a commutative von Neumann regular ring.  The idempotents of $R$ are precisely the characteristic functions $1_K$ of clopen sets $K$.  An orthogonal decomposition of $1_K$ into idempotents corresponds to writing $K$ as a disjoint union of clopen sets.  Since $X$ has no isolated points, if $K$ is a nonempty clopen set, there are $x\neq y\in K$.  Then we can find a clopen subset $K'$ of $K$ with $x\in K'$ and $y\notin K'$.  Thus $1_K = 1_{K'}+1_{K\setminus K'}$ is a decomposition into orthogonal idempotents.  If follows that $R$ has no primitive idempotents and hence no indecomposable summands (as an indecomposable summand is of the form $eR$ with $e$ primitive).

Answer (score 3):

**No**, a [free Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Boolean_algebra) $R$ on an infinite cardinal $\kappa$ (e.g., if $\kappa = \aleph_0$, $R$ is the Cantor algebra), is a commutative von Neumann regular ring which is not well complemented as an $R$-module.

Comment: +1. But I can only accept one answer, and I'm accepting Benjamin Steinberg's answer since it came first and has a few more details.

Comment: @SalvoTringali No worry, that's totally fair.